# Live incrementing a Counter from code behind in a textBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF App which loops in Codebehind through data and increments a counter for each found element.

Now I would like to display the live incrementing counter as status feedback to the user.

All I get now is the value after my task has finished because we need to run it as await task.

Button Click fires the method which loops my data.

Can I update the counter in my Xaml if my method runs and not after finishing?

---

Solution form mm8:

Code Behind:

```
public partial class UserControlCounter : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _scanStatusCounter;
    public int ScanStatusCounter
    {
        get { return _scanStatusCounter; }
        set { _scanStatusCounter = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public UserControlCounter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        await Task.Run(getAll);
        scanStatus.Text = "Persons " + ScanStatusCounter.ToString();
    }


    private async void getAll()
    {
        //grab data and iterate it
        string[] string_array = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" }; // type = System.String[]

        foreach (var i in string_array)
        {

            ScanStatusCounter++;
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

That's my Xaml for the Control:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="scanStatus" Text="{Binding Path=ScanStatusCounter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click"> Click Me</Button>
</Grid>
```

thank you

**Updated working Solution added.
Thanks in advance to mm8 for holding my hand!**

Comment: as  a user of software, I would *hate* the fact that developer added a delay (`await Task.Delay(100);`) just to show fancy progress. if you run operation in a Task (which you do), then delays are not needed, they simply steal time

Comment: thats of because its just for prototyping and not for real world with big data. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and make `scanStatusCounter` a property:

```
public partial class UserControlCounter : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _scanStatusCounter;
    public int ScanStatusCounter
    {
        get { return _scanStatusCounter; }
        set { _scanStatusCounter = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public UserControlCounter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = sender as Button;
        var contentPresenter = (btn.TemplatedParent as ContentPresenter);

        var ppStatusCounter = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate.FindName("scanStatus", contentPresenter) as TextBlock;

        await Task.Run(getAll);
        ppStatusCounter.Text = "Persons " + ScanStatusCounter.ToString();
    }


    private static async void getAll()
    {
        //grab data and iterate it

        foreach (var result in data)
        {
            ScanStatusCounter++;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You may also want to add some delay in the loop to actually be able see the counter being incremented:

```
private static async void getAll()
{
    //grab data and iterate it

    foreach (var result in data)
    {
        ScanStatusCounter++;
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi mm8, thank you for your answer. Now with your code I get the real value after Click again, on first Click Im getting 1 as value. On next Click 11 and the next 21 and so on. Ive updatet my Class with your Code.

Comment: @CodCase: You need to reset the value after each click: `ScanStatusCounter = 0;`.

Comment: Hm thank you, but that changes not the behaivior that the Counter doesnt start to increment live if i click on my Button.

Comment: @CodCase: What does "increment live" mean? Did you add the delay?

Comment: @CodCase: If not, you will probably not get a chance to see the updates one by one as they happen too fast.

Comment: Ive added an dummydata Array to the foreach clause for testing. Ive also tested the code with long delays but I still get the proper value only if I click again. Isnt it, that if it runs too fast, we should see on first click the number of entrys (5) from the array? Now on first click I get 0 on the next Click 5 and so on.

Comment: @CodCase: You should see the `TextBlock` in the view that is bound to `ScanStatusCounter` get incremented for each iteration in the loop.

Comment: Im sorry didnt increment. Ive also tryed a complete new project (wpf core) just with the code from here and its the same for me. Maybe there is another issue wich I didnt have in view :) Ive updated my example with yours and the new wpf project code for testing.

Comment: @CodCase: You don't seem to bind to the `ScanStatusCounter` property in the view?

Comment: Hi mm8, IVe updated my Code with Binding to the View, that should work I think?

Comment: @CodCase: You also need to set the `DataContext` of the window to itself where the source property is defined. Try to add `DataContext = this;` in the constructor below the call to `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: finally lol, forgot the most in the proto code. Thank you so mcuh. Ive update the Code above with the complete Solution. Thank you so much!